# Как загрузить несколько файлов на сервер Spring

Tags: java, html, spring

**multipart/form-data** даёт возможность загрузить только 1 файл за раз(как я понимаю), как сделать массовую отправку файлов через 1 форму?

Comment: 1. Создайте нулячий html + form Поставьте `<input type="file" multiple>` и посмотрите как обрабатыватся запрос. 2. Либо почитайте спецификацию http.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Атрибут формы `enctype` равный `multipart/form-data` указывает на факт того, что из формы могут загружаться файлы, а не на количество загружаемых файлов. Чтобы загрузить несколько файлов из одной формы, надо либо добавить несколько полей соответствующего типа, либо добавить в одно поле атрибут `multiple`.

На бэкенде, по сравнению с загрузкой одного файла, не меняется ничего, кроме смены типа принимаемого контроллером аргумента на массив:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, Model model) {
    for(MultipartFile file : files) {
        ...
    }
    return "redirect:/upload/success"
}
```